# Outlook add-in cannot GET "https://telemetryservice.firstpartyapps.oaspapps.com/telemetryservice/telemetryproxy.html"

Tags: exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm testing my Outlook add-in in OWA. When I try to use an EWS SOAP call to get the list of folders for the user it's unable to do so. In the browser console I receive a 404 error for `GET https://telemetryservice.firstpartyapps.oaspapps.com/telemetryservice/telemetryproxy.html` in `o15apptofilemappingtable.js:11`

When opening the add-in I also receive an error saying: `Error while parsing the 'sandbox' attribute: 'ms-allow-popups' is an invalid sandbox flag.` in `osfruntime.js:12`

The domain for this user is backed by Exchange 2013 SP1, and this behavior also occurs in Outlook 2016.

Any ideas on what might be causing these errors and if they're related?

Comment: Both the 404 for telemetryproxy.html and the sandbox errors should not affect EWS. Are you using makeEwsRequestAsync API? And which EWS soap call are you making (GetFolder or something else?)?  In case this helps, this is the related docs for using EWS in addins  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services

Comment: We are using makeEwsRequestAsync to make the EWS API calls. I've tested this using an account in the outlook.com domain and it works fine. However our exchange backed domain is unable to complete any of the SOAP calls (GetFolder, MoveItem, ForwardItem, GetItem).

Comment: Since this is happening in both desktop and web clients, it's likely that the Exchange Server isn't set up to process the EWS calls? Getting a fiddler trace may also show you what specific error the server is returning.

Comment: The Exchange server can process EWS without an issue. Using the EWS Editor linked from the Microsoft EWS documentation the GetFolder call returns with the list of folders just fine.

Comment: I used Fiddler to trace the requests and the only difference between our Exchange backed domain and an outlook.com account (where the EWS request return correctly) were the 404 errors for telemetryproxy.html.

Comment: On the buggy accounts, you are seeing an EWS call in the fiddler and a response?

Comment: I see a `GetClientAccessToken` call with a 200 response, but no other calls for the broken account. The working account has an `ExecuteEwsProxy` call after the `GetClientAccessToken`.

Comment: We tried but couldn't reproduce the issue you are seeing. Is this issue being faced by a single user or multiple users? What is the Exchange version number and version number for Desktop Outlook?

Comment: This is happening to all users for that domain. Exchange Server 2013 CU20  March 20, 2018  15.00.1367.003

I'm fairly certain it's not related to any Desktop Outlook issues as this also happens when using OWA in a web browser.

Comment: Here's the Outlook version: Microsoft Outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.10228.20051) 32-bit

Comment: Can you let us know what you got back as response from the getClientAccessToken call? Was there an actual token that was returned in the response body?